# C++: pointers to data members or traits?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm practicing with some binary tree algorithms in C++ and trying to write as generic code as possible. In particular, I would like my functions (algorithms) be able to operate on any (to some extend, of course) tree-like data structures.

A tree node structure might be defined in different ways, like this, for instance:

```
struct binary_tree_node
{
    int data;
    struct binary_tree_node *left;
    struct binary_tree_node *right;
};
```

Or like this:

```
struct binary_tree_node2
{
    long key;
    struct binary_tree_node2 *first_child;
    struct binary_tree_node2 *second_child;
};
```

Or anyhow else, but pretty similar to that pattern.
So I would like my functions/algorithms be able to work with any of these or similar data structures.

For example, here is how I define one simple function:

```
template <typename TreeNode, typename DataType = typename TreeNode::data_type>
TreeNode*
binary_tree_new_node(DataType value = DataType(),
                     DataType  TreeNode::* data  = &TreeNode::data,
                     TreeNode* TreeNode::* left  = &TreeNode::left,
                     TreeNode* TreeNode::* right = &TreeNode::right)
{
    TreeNode *newnode = new TreeNode();
    newnode->*data  = value;
    newnode->*left  = nullptr;
    newnode->*right = nullptr;
    return newnode;
}
```

Thus, it is possible to use the function with any suitable tree-node type of your choice. If the data members have different names (not `data`, `left` and `right`), then one can call the function and pass the pointers to the corresponding data members. This way, the function does not depend on (or at least can adjust itself to) how the data members of the input type are named.

It worked pretty well so far, but as I implement more and more functions, I'm getting tired of these pointer-to-data-member parameters which I have to list as optional parameters of the functions. So is there any better way to handle this? Maybe some sort of traits? Or somehow else?

I would like to keep the requirements on the input type as few as possible. For example, the client program should not be forced to define anything more than just the tree-node type. It shall not also be forced to use/derive-from any provided types or templates. Of course, the client program might re-use some of the provided templates, like the one below, which I also define, but should not really be forced to.

```
template<typename T>
struct binary_tree_node
{
    using data_type = T;
    data_type data;
    struct binary_tree_node *left;
    struct binary_tree_node *right;
};
```

What are the available options here?
Does it make any sense at all? :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Other than supporting differently named fields, your code doesn't seem very generic.  It wouldn't support a tree that used `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` to store its children, or one where children had a `weak_ptr` pointing at their parents, or one where the tree stores its children in a `std::vector<>`, or a myriad of other variations.  Instead of operating directly on the tree, I'd be tempted to find some primitive operations and operate on those.  Then have those primitive operations be dependent on `traits` of whatever kind...

Comment: @Yakk What is the problem with *_ptr? `std::vector<>` makes it more than a binary tree. The idea about primitive operations sounds nice, but for the basic binary tree, it's just following either left or right child.

Comment: So, I pointed out 4 ways your design is flawed (`unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr`, nodes that want to do something when they are modified, possibility pointer storage doesn't exist until required), and you have responded to one of them.  Are the other 3 insufficient to throw out your design?  As for `std::vector`, an N-ary tree supports all binary tree operations (set/get first child, set/get second child, set/get node data), so a good binary tree abstraction should be able to wrap creating an N-ary tree as binary: Your cannot, which is a sign that your abstraction is poor.

Comment: @Yakk I'm not trying to build a perfect abstraction here and asked how to improve one particular thing. However, thanks for your thoughts and feedback, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The way the STL collection libraries work is that the author of the tree library would supply the node class so that all the user of the template needs to do is supply the data.  The other option which you seem to be going for are intrusive data structures(that would be a good term to google for ideas). With those you have a couple of choices, the first is require the data members to be left, right, and data. Second require access functions with a specific name so the template can find them.  Third require functors to be passed in as template parameters so you can use them to find the data you need.  Personally I find the STL way the least messy, followed by the functors approach.

Comment: I would not completely agree on the "the author of the tree library would supply the node class" part. By doing this, and if the node class is a must to use, the author binds the algorithms to the class, which is practically the same as defining the algorithms as methods of the class, which is (to my understanding at least) not the way STL/boost or similar libs are supposed to be.

Comment: @alveko  You the user of standard list never define a list node. The same applies to Map or any of the other standard containers that need a node to work with.  The node is defined internal to the container. If you are in VS2012 open up the list header and search for struct _List_node.  It defines a node structure with _Next _Prev and _Myval for the data.

Answer (score 0):

To make your algorithm as generic as possible I recommend using functors. Your binary_tree_new_node would look like

```
template<typename G, typename L, typename R, typename AT, typename AD, typename D>
auto binary_tree_new_node(
    G generator,
    L left,
    R right,
    AT assign_tree,
    AD assign_data,
    D data) ->decltype( generator() )
{
    auto  tree = generator();
    auto& l    = left(tree);
    auto& r    = right(tree);
    assign_data(tree, data);
    assign_tree(l, nullptr);
    assign_tree(r, nullptr);
    return tree;
}
```

For your binary_tree_node, the functors would look like:

```
// WARNING!!! Very dangerous code!!!

binary_tree_node* generator()
{
    return new binary_tree_node;
}

binary_tree_node*& left(binary_tree_node* tree)
{
    return tree->left;
}

binary_tree_node*& right(binary_tree_node* tree)
{
    return tree->right;
}

void assign_data(binary_tree_node* node, int data)
{
    node->data = data;
}

void assign_tree(binary_tree_node*& node, binary_tree_node* data)
{
    node = data;
}
```